# Fetch data from two tables with different conditions without relation

Tags: mysql

I have two tables, `agency` and `hotel`
I want to fetch data from this two where they have `flag = 1`
both of tables have flag. How can I do it in one query?

maybe something like this (but it is not working):

```
select agency.*,hotel.* FROM agency,hotel WHERE agency.flag = 1 OR hotel.flag = 1
```

Comment: You could use `union` clause for that but only if both tables have the same columns, which I doubt.

Comment: I need to return number of rows of each table, is it possible? in union it returns all tables rows in one variable!

Comment: If you need only the number of rows: `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM agency WHERE flag=1 UNION SELECT COUNT(*) FROM hotel WHERE flag=1;`

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score -1):

You need to join the tables by some column ( mainly key column) which is common between two tables, else it will be cartesian product.

```
select agency.*,hotel.* FROM agency,hotel WHERE agency.<column> = hotel.<column> and (agency.flag = 1 OR hotel.flag = 1)
```

Find the common key column and  it will work.